# Send e-mail dependant on specific cell contents

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am a novice VBA programmer and I have searched for this but am unable to find a solution that exactly matches what I need.

I have a code to ping out customer's IP address but I only need e-mail notifications for the pings that have timed out.

The ping results are in column D and the e-mails are in column E of my spreadsheet.  I'd be grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

```
Dim OutlookApp
Dim objMail
Dim x As Long
Dim PingResults As range


lastrow = Sheets("Ping").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow

Set PingResults = range("d2:D250")
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

If PingResults.Cells.Value = "Request timed out." Then

objMail.To = Cells(x, 5).Value

With objMail
.Subject = Cells(x, 1) & " " & "-" & " " & Cells(x, 2) & " " & "-" & " " & Cells(x, 3)
.Body = "Run Diagnostics.  Customer's broadband appears to have issues" & vbCrLf & Cells(x, 4)
.Display
.Save
End With

SendKeys "%{s}", True

ElseIf PingResults.Cells.Value = "" Then


Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: and what's your issue with the shown code?

Comment: I can't see a `Next x`...? Indenting code helps with that..

Comment: Also, `If PingResults.Cells.Value = "Request timed out." Then` on a range of 249 cells is not going to work. Perhaps you meant `PingResults.Cells(x,1).Value` ?

Comment: Hi user3598756 and CLR, the code doesn't do anything but throw up an error code stating "compile error: For without Next" but when I put Next between ' ElseIf PingResults.Cells.Value = "" Then ' and ' Set OutlookApp = Nothing '.  the compile error is Next without a For, but a For is in there.

Comment: Yes, we can see what's wrong with your code, which is why we've both re-written it to include a `Next` (in the right place) - and also a few other bits to improve/correct.

Answer (score 1):

you most probably are after this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim pingResults As Range, cell As Range

    With Sheets("Ping")
        With .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Request timed out."
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set pingResults = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    If Not pingResults Is Nothing Then
        With CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            For Each cell In pingResults
                With .CreateItem(0) '<--| olMailItem is an item of an OutLook enumeration whose value is "zero"
                    .Display
                    .to = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
                    .Subject = cell.Offset(, -3) & " " & "-" & " " & cell.Offset(, -2) & " " & "-" & " " & cell.Offset(, -1)
                    .Body = "Run Diagnostics.  Customer's broadband appears to have issues" & vbCrLf & cell.Value
                    .Save
                End With
                SendKeys "%{s}", True
            Next
            .Quit
        End With
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: @user7832015, did you get through it? If so, then please mark answer as accepted. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Dim OutlookApp
Dim objMail
Dim x As Long
Dim PingResults As Range

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
lastrow = Sheets("Ping").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set PingResults = Range("d1:D" & lastrow)

For x = 2 To lastrow

    If PingResults.Cells(x, 1).Value = "Request timed out." Then
        Set objMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With objMail
            .To = Cells(x, 5).Value
            .Subject = Cells(x, 1) & " " & "-" & " " & Cells(x, 2) & " " & "-" & " " & Cells(x, 3)
            .Body = "Run Diagnostics.  Customer's broadband appears to have issues" & vbCrLf & Cells(x, 4)
            .Display
            .Save
        End With

        SendKeys "%{s}", True
        Set objMail = Nothing

    End If
Next x
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Sorry, one more thing.  how can the e-mail be sent without me having to select 'don't Exit' in the outlook pop up message

Comment: Not sure what you mean, my answer runs fine on my set-up with no popups at all?

Comment: Hi CLR, yours is fine it's user7832015 script but I removed the .Quit and it's fine.  Again, many thanks!!!